# Laravel 8 validating arrays

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

I have a Laravel 8 form with an array of user contact details.

```
<div> 

<input name="contactdetails[{{ $key }}][email]" type="text"> 

<input name=" contactdetails [{{ $key }}][mobile]" type="text"> 

</div 

<div> 

<input name=" contactdetails [{{ $key }}][email]" type="text"> 

<input name=" contactdetails [{{ $key }}][mobile]" type="text"> 

</div 

<div> 

<input name=" contactdetails [{{ $key }}][email]" type="text"> 

<input name=" contactdetails [{{ $key }}][mobile]" type="text"> 

</div
```

My validation rule looks like this:

```
contactdetails.*.email=> ‘email:rfc,dns’, 

contactdetails.*. mobile => required_with:email|numeric',
```

I need to validate that at least one email was entered but not all, and the corresponding mobile.

The result is never an empty array.

```
contactdetails: array:7 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "email" => null
      "mobile" => null
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
    2 => array:5 [▶]
    3 => array:5 [▶]
    4 => array:5 [▶]
    5 => array:5 [▶]
    6 => array:5 [▶]
  ]
```

Comment: in this code you have fields with the same name

Comment: Because they are arrays :)

Comment: assuming `$key` magically changes between each `div`, sure. If not you need to name them as `contactdetails [{{ $key }}][mobile][]`

Comment: $key magically changes between each div

Answer (score 0):

you must do it :

```
'contactdetails' => 'array|min:1',
'contactdetails.*.email' => 'email:rfc,dns',
'contactdetails.*.mobile' => 'required_with:contactdetails.*.email|numeric',
```

this means contactdetails must be array and have at least one member
and better add a regex mobile rule for validate correct mobile number

Comment: I've updated the details to show that the array is always greater than 1